# Receiving inconsistent counts from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

We are using rest api to execute queries in cassandra and one of our query which fetches count is creating problems for us.

We have built cassandra cluster and recently, we have done backup and restore and copied all the data to new cluster. 
We have done nodetool refresh on the tables, and did the nodetool repair as well.

However, some of our API calls are failing and returning inconsistent results.

1) The count query has partition keys in it. Didnt see any read timeout or any errors from api call.

2) This is how our code of creating session looks.

```
val poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions
    poolingOptions
      .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 4)
      .setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 10)
      .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 4)
      .setMaxConnectionsPerHost( HostDistance.REMOTE, 10)

val builtCluster = clusterBuilder.withCredentials(username, password)
      .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
      .build()
val cassandraSession = builtCluster.get.connect()
val preparedStatement = cassandraSession.prepare(statement).setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
cassandraSession.execute(preparedStatement.bind(args :_*))
```

**Cluster configuration:**

6 Machines: 3 seeds

cassandra is never down on any machine

we are using apache cassandra 3.9 version

Using cassandra-driver-core artifact with 3.1.1 version.

3) nodetoop tpstats shows no failures.

4) Do not see any other issues from system.log of cassandra. We just see few warnings as below.

```
Maximum memory usage reached (512.000MiB), cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB
WARN  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2017-03-14 14:58:37,141 QueryProcessor.java:103 - 88 prepared statements discarded in the last minute because cache limit reached (32 MB)
```

The first api call returns 0 and the api calls later gives right values.

Please let me know, if any other details needed.

Comment: what is your table structure and what query are you executing ?

Comment: We have table with 4 columns, one of them is partition key and couple of columns(a date column + a text column) has been selected as clustering key. Our queries will look like this.  SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE parition_column=? AND text_column_of_clustering_key=? AND date_column_of_clustering_key<=? AND date_column_of_clustering_key>=?

Comment: Whats your replication strategy/factor? What consistency level do the writes to that table come in at?

Comment: Replication factor is 3, and write consistency is ONE and read consistency is QUORUM.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use count(*), use counter**
`count(*)` is very inefficient. Cassandra need to scan all the row just to give you the count. If you have huge amount of data cassandra can throw you timeout exception.

**Use counter Instead :**

> A counter is a special column used to store a number that is changed in increments. For example, you might use a counter column to count the number of times a page is viewed.

Let's define a table :

```
CREATE TABLE counter_test (
    pk int,
    ctkey text,
    cdkey date,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (pk, ctkey, cdkey)
);
```

Increase the value of the counter :

```
UPDATE counter_test SET count = count + 10 WHERE pk = 1 AND ctkey = 'hi' AND cdkey = '2017-03-16';
```

Decrease the value of the counter :

```
UPDATE counter_test SET count = count - 5 WHERE pk = 1 AND ctkey = 'hi' AND cdkey = '2017-03-16';
```

Select the value of counter :

```
SELECT * FROM counter_test WHERE pk = 1 AND ctkey = 'hi' AND cdkey = '2017-03-16';
```

you will get :

```
 pk | ctkey | cdkey      | count
----+-------+------------+-------
  1 |    hi | 2017-03-16 |     5
```

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Comment: I do not think the counter works for our scenario. As we update the dump the data the volume of data is also very high. Updating the counter every time will be a performance hit and not really solves our problem.